# Support for interactive bash terminal input in a Telegram Bot on Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, telegram, telegram-bot

I wrote a simple telegram bot in Python that working in this way:
User message - a command that will be sent to the bash terminal of the bot host using the subproces library
bot respond - a terminal output.
I ran into a problem that scripts and tools that use interactive input cannot be used (for example, sudo) so I have to go into the terminal.

Question: can I make similar support for interactive input and how? Code below

```py
import subprocess
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

TOKEN = ""

def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("First Message.")

# Execute 
def execute_command(update, context):
    # Get
    command = update.message.text
    try:
        # Result
        result = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, text=True)
        # Send
        update.message.reply_text(result)
    except Exception as e:
        # Errors
        update.message.reply_text(f"Ошибка: {str(e)}")

# Main func
def main():
    # Updater
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, execute_command))

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()

if name == "main":
    main()
```

I think its possible to do this with pexpect library, but I didn't understood how to yet.